# Help with consuming JSON feed with PHP & json_decode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I've having an issue with consuming a particular feed for a client. They have given me a remote URL and the response is a JSON string like so:

```
{"affiliate": [
{"ID":"1", "COUNTRY":"EXAMPLE", "NETWORK":"EXAMPLE", "PRIMARY":"EXAMPLE"},
{"ID":"2", "EXAMPLE":"EXAMPLE", "COUNTRY":"EXAMPLE", "NETWORK":"EXAMPLE", "PRIMARY":"EXAMPLE"},
{"ID":"3", "TITLE":"EXAMPLE", "COUNTRY":"EXAMPLE", "NETWORK":"EXAMPLE", "PRIMARY":"EXAMPLE"}
]}
```

For example purposes, I've shrank the feed to show the format, but in actuality there are hundreds of affiliates. Anyway, I want to use PHP json_decode because in the end, I need these affiliates in an associative array.

I've got something like this, but I just end up getting the raw string, and json_decode doesn't actually parse it into an associative array.

```
$request_url = "http://exampleurl.com/feed"; //returns feed like above

$json = file_get_contents($request_url, true); //getting the file content

$decode = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($decode);
```

It seems like I need to maintain the "\n" characters in the feed itself, but these get stripped out when using:

```
file_get_contents
```

Anyway, I think you know what I'm after, I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong. I appreciate the help in advance. I've tried using jquery with jsonp but it would be more ideal this way since I need to sort through the array afterward and it doesn't need to be asynchronous.

Acorn

Comment: I noticed you changes the code. I ran the code with the correct print_r and it worked fine with the sample data. Could you provide the feed you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that your feed contains unicode text. Try:

```
$decode = json_decode(addslashes($json), true)
```

---

Update:

Solved the problem. There are instances of `\'s` in the json data which `json_decode` doesn't handle properly. To solve this you need to double escape the `\`. This is what I did.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$request_url = 'http://midas.glam.com/publisher_directory_data?network=glam&country=US&publish=Y';

$json = file_get_contents($request_url);
$json = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $json);

$decode = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($decode);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but that is actually what I had in my code. Sorry for the confusion. The result is that the print_r function spits out the raw JSON feed instead of the associative array. Any other ideas?

Comment: Updated my answer, might not be the problem but its worth a try.

Comment: Tried this and it just spits out the slashes along with the rest of the JSON string.

Comment: Would it have something to do with the fact that the feed isn't contained within () or [] ?

Comment: It works fine when I copy the raw xml file into a string, so I think the problem is with `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Thanks for this. The str_replace() worked. I appreciate the help!This has been plaguing me for a couple of days now.

Answer (score 4):

You're data feed escapes single quotes (apostrophes) with a backslash (e.g. \').  The JSON spec doesn't say this should be done, and thus PHP doesn't behave correctly.

See: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42708

You can try replacing all \' with ':

```
$json = str_replace('\\\'', "'", $json);
```

before calling json_decode.