# How to do regex in following Data using PHP

Tags: php, regex

```
// [ { "id": "715320" ,"t" : "500268" ,"e" : "BOM" ,"l" : "15.55" ,"l_cur" : "Rs.15.55" 
,"ltt":"3:59PM IST" ,"lt" : "Sep 9, 3:59PM IST" ,"c" : "+1.69" ,"cp" : "12.19" 
,"ccol" : "chg" } ]
```

I need to Get each with name and assign the value to each

Like 
$id=715320;
$e=BOM;

from above data, how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string totally looks like a JSon data. You should use the [JSon methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) to parse the content.

---

If your really want to use regexes you can do this :

```
<?php
$yourString = '// [ { "id": "715320" ,"t" : "500268" ,"e" : "BOM" ,"l" : "15.55" ,"l_cur" : "Rs.15.55" 
,"ltt":"3:59PM IST" ,"lt" : "Sep 9, 3:59PM IST" ,"c" : "+1.69" ,"cp" : "12.19" 
,"ccol" : "chg" } ] ';

preg_match_all("/\"(.+?)\"\s*:\s*\"(.+?)\"/", $yourString, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
 
foreach($matches as $match){
    $resultArray[$match[1]] = $match[2];
}
 
print_r($resultArray);
 
?>
```

[Code on ideone](http://ideone.com/UTQ4e)

---

Is used an array instead of variables in this code, but if you do really want to use variables such as `$e` which is a really really bad idea, you can use *variable variables*.

You replace the foreach content by this :
`${$match[1]} = $match[2];`

---

**Resources :**

- [php.net json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

**On the same topic :**

- [Help with consuming JSON feed with PHP & json_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200603/help-with-consuming-json-feed-with-php-json-decode)

Answer (score 3):

As that's JSON encoded data, you can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) rather than a regex - this is far more reliable (be sure to remove the leading `\\` as that's a comment rather than JSON).

To then get the data into named variables:

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);
foreach ($array as $k => $v){
    $$k = $v;
}
```

This will result in `id`, `t` etc (which are now keys in $array) being set as their own variables like `$id`, `$t` .

edit: as [aularon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690614/how-to-do-regex-in-following-data-using-php/3690632#3690632) notes, you can also use the [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) method to move the array keys to the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that simply JSON? Then take a look at [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Or is there a reason you need to do this with a Regex?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions, above is a JSON object notation, you need to do php [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) on it, get the values, which will be an associative array:

```
$str='[ { "id": "715320" ,"t" : "500268" ,"e" : "BOM" ,"l" : "15.55" ,"l_cur" : "Rs.15.55" 
,"ltt":"3:59PM IST" ,"lt" : "Sep 9, 3:59PM IST" ,"c" : "+1.69" ,"cp" : "12.19" 
,"ccol" : "chg" } ] ';

$data=json_decode($str, true); //true to get the data as associative arrays rather than objects.
$data = $data[0];//since it's an object inside an array
```

from now on it's recommended keeping this as an associative array, and access objects using array accessors:

```
$id = $data['id'];
```

PHP's [`extract`](http://php.net/extract) function can be used to extract those values into current context, but that is dangerous, sticking to the accessing the array directly is a better idea.